# couchdb server admin created in script cannot create database in the same script

Tags: purescript, couchdb-2.0

In the same script, I can succesfully create a server admin on the /_config/admins/, then log in as that admin on the _session endpoint. 
The response is:

```
{"ok":true,"name":"cor","roles":["_admin"]}
```

However, I then cannot create a database:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
```

That is, not until I close the session and start another, authenticating and creating the database in exactly the same way.

I tried to wait (2000 msec) but that is no solution.

I run Couchdb 2.1.1. The script is Javascript, compiled from Purescript.

This is the Purescript source:

```
    module Test.Couchdb where

    import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff)
    import Data.Argonaut (fromString)
    import Data.Argonaut.Core (fromObject)
    import Data.Foreign.Generic (defaultOptions, genericDecode)
    import Data.Foreign.NullOrUndefined (NullOrUndefined)
    import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
    import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
    import Data.Newtype (class Newtype)
    import Data.StrMap (fromFoldable) as StrMap
    import Data.Tuple (Tuple(..))
    import Network.HTTP.Affjax (AJAX, post, put, AffjaxResponse)
    import Network.HTTP.Affjax.Response (class Respondable, ResponseType(..))
    import Prelude (Unit, bind, pure, unit, ($), (<>))

    -- Run this function on a couchdb 2.1.1 instance with CORS set up or from the localhost.
    -- Puts a new admin with the given user name and password.
    -- Then creates a session.
    -- Finally tries to create a database.
    -- No analysis on what is returned from the server for clarities sake.
    -- This code fails, because the database cannot be created because: "You are not a server admin.". 
    test :: forall e. String -> String -> String -> Aff (ajax :: AJAX | e) Unit
    test usr pwd dbName = do
      (_ :: AffjaxResponse String) <- put ("http://127.0.0.1:5984/_node/couchdb@localhost/_config/admins/" <> usr) (fromString pwd)
      (_ :: AffjaxResponse PostCouchdb_session) <- post "http://127.0.0.1:5984/_session"
        (fromObject (StrMap.fromFoldable [Tuple "name" (fromString usr), Tuple "password" (fromString pwd)]))
      -- the argument to post is in essence {"name": <usr>, "password": <pwd>}
      (_ :: AffjaxResponse String) <-put ("http://127.0.0.1:5984/" <> dbName) ""
      pure unit

    -- Just a definition for the return value of post.
    newtype PostCouchdb_session = PostCouchdb_session
      { ok :: Boolean
      , name :: NullOrUndefined String
      , roles :: Array String
      }
    derive instance genericPostCouchdb_session :: Generic PostCouchdb_session _
    derive instance newtypePostCouchdb_session :: Newtype PostCouchdb_session _
    instance respondablePostCouchdb_session :: Respondable PostCouchdb_session where
      responseType = Tuple Nothing JSONResponse
      fromResponse = genericDecode $ defaultOptions {unwrapSingleConstructors = true}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Affjax library convenience functions (such as put and get) rely on a defaultRequest object that has 'withCredentials' set to false. This prevents browsers from saving cookies sent by the server in a cross-domain request. Hence, even after succesfully authenticating with Couchdb, the session cookie is not stored and thus a next attempt to perform an action on the server will fail.